# unable to find attribute constraintSet

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-constraintlayout

I had this error after I accidentally deleted something on a .debug file.

> Error:In  ConstraintLayout_Layout, unable to find attribute layout_constraintBaseline_creator
>   Error:In  ConstraintSet, unable to find attribute layout_constraintBaseline_creator

Here is my build.gradle code

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapp.project.com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}
```

Do you have an idea how to fix this error? This error has not been removed even if I pull a new project from git. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you tried to clean the project? Project menu -> clean project

Comment: Yes. Same error though :(( @KMI

Comment: You can paste your build.gradle code

Comment: I edited my question @KMI thanks